# Rails change a variable based on button push

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a weekly spreadsheet type display of hours for an employee. It displays this week fine.  But, I'd like them to be able to go forward a week or back a week.

The working display code is:

```
<% showdate = DateTime.now%>
<td><strong><%= showdate.beginning_of_week.to_date - 1.day%></strong></td>
<td><strong><%= showdate.beginning_of_week.to_date %></strong></td>
<td><strong><%= showdate.beginning_of_week.to_date + 1.day %></strong></td>
<td><strong><%= showdate.beginning_of_week.to_date + 2.day  %></strong></td>
<td><strong><%= showdate.beginning_of_week.to_date + 3.day  %></strong></td>
<td><strong><%= showdate.beginning_of_week.to_date + 4.day  %></strong></td>
<td><strong><%= showdate.beginning_of_week.to_date + 5.day  %></strong></td>
```

I have a button group:

```
<div class="btn-group-wrap">
 <button class="btn btn-primary">- 1</button>
<button class="btn btn-success">+ 1</button>
```

When the user presses the -1 button, I would like to change the showdate to -1.week and refresh the page.

How would I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assignment of showdate could be `<% showdate = DateTime.now + (params[:offset].to_i.weeks %>` and then the +1 button could go to `http://your/url?offset=<%= params[:offset].to_i + 1 %>`.